# Shell script to edit a large text file

Tags: shell

I need to append the server name to the front of each user entry associated with that server. Below is an example of the file I'm curently dealing with:

```
<server_name>
at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/bin/bash
<server_name>
at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/bin/bash
```

I need a script to strip out the server name and append it to the front of the user entry. So the file would end up looking like this:

```
<server_name_a>
<server_name_a>:at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
<server_name_a>:bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/bin/bash
<server_name_b>
<server_name_b>:at:x:25:25:Batch jobs daemon:/var/spool/atjobs:/bin/bash
<server_name_b>:bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/bin/bash
```

Comment: awk is a better tool for what you want.

Comment: You're doing a security audit, but can't write a basic text processing script in some language to help automate something? Hopefully this company has someone doing a security audit on your security audit?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple `awk` program that should do what you're describing:

```
awk '/^INFO/{prefix=$NF;next}{printf "%s:%s\n", prefix, $0}' < ${FILENAME} > ${OUTPUT}
```

Comment: Or, if the INFO: lines should be kept, like in the sample

    awk '/^INFO/{prefix=$NF;print;next}{printf "%s:%s\n", prefix, $0}' < ${FILENAME} > ${OUTPUT}

Best, however, would have been, if the servername could have prepended while the data was collected...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $* | while read line
do
    if echo $line | grep "^INFO:" > /dev/null
    then
        SERVER=`echo "$line" | sed -e 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/g'`
    else 
        echo $SERVER:$line
    fi
done
```